# How to fix? TypeError: argument of type 'PasswordManager' is not iterable

Tags: python, list, class, methods, typeerror

I keep getting the following error and I can't seem to find a solution for it.

```
    if password not in old_passwords:
TypeError: argument of type 'PasswordManager' is not iterable
```

For clarity, I needed to create a class called 'PasswordManager'. The class should have a list called 'old_passwords'. The list contains all past passwords, the last index of the list should be the current password. The required methods are 'set_password', 'get_password' and 'is_correct'.

'get_password' should return the current  password.

'set_password' sets a new password. It should only change the password if the attempted password is different from all the user’s past passwords.

'is_correct' receives a string and returns a boolean True or False depending on whether the string is equal to the current password or not.

```
class PasswordManager():
    old_passwords = []
    def get_password(old_passwords):
        return old_passwords[len(old_passwords-1)]

    def set_password(old_passwords, password):
        if password not in old_passwords:
            old_passwords.append(password)

    def is_correct(old_passwords, password):
        if password == old_passwords[len(old_passwords-1)]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Does anyone have an idea that could help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are your methods missing the argument `self`?

Comment: one suggestion, to get the last element in a list you can use -1 as the index, for example, `a_list[-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to review how to use classes in python.
Your class needs a **constructor**, where you can instantiate your class attributes (in your case `old_passwords`) and you can access them with `self`.
An example of your use case could be

```
class PasswordManager():
  
  def __init__(self):
    self.old_passwords = []

  def get_password(self):
    return self.old_passwords[-1]

  def set_password(self, password):
    if password not in self.old_passwords:
        self.old_passwords.append(password)

  def is_correct(self, password):
    return password == self.old_passwords[-1]
```

With `[-1]` you can access the last element of a list.
`__init__` is the constructor method in python.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer! I'm pretty new to working with classes, so this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

python class methods require first argument as class itself. moreover, you cannot directly access class variables or methods in its methods.
 need to use something like `self.somemethod()` or `self.somevariable`

```
class PasswordManager():
    old_passwords = []
    def get_password(self):
        return self.old_passwords[-1]

    def set_password(self, password):
        if password not in self.old_passwords:
            self.old_passwords.append(password)

    def is_correct(self, password):
        if password == self.old_passwords[-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

also, you are accessing last item in list wrong way.
`old_passwords[len(old_passwords-1)]` should be `old_passwords[len(old_passwords)-1]`.
 but, `old_passwords[-1]` is better choice.